# C: dup2() before execv

Tags: c, exec, fork, file-descriptor

For a homework assignment I have to write a basic shell including redirection. The program uses readline to prompt for input, parses the input string, and breaks it down into the executable name, the arguments, and the input/output file(s), if applicable. After parsing the string, it forks and the child execv()'s to the executable that was passed in. I'm using dup2() to change the file descriptors after the fork and before the execv, but am having a problem once the program has execv'd to the new executable. If in my shell I run `ls > foo.out`, I get: `ls: cannot access H��y�A�
                         $ L��H)�I��$�: No such file or directory`

Construction of c->argv:

```
char *args[6];

int i;
for(i=0;i<=4;i++){
    char *_arg=strsep(&_str_cmd," ");
    printf("Found _arg: %s\n",_arg);

    // If there is an argument and it is not blank
    if(_arg && strcmp(_arg,"")!=0){
        if(strcmp(_arg,"<")==0){
            _cmd.infile=strsep(&_str_cmd," ");
            i--;
            continue;
        }
        else if(strcmp(_arg,">")==0){
            _cmd.outfile=strsep(&_str_cmd," ");
            i--;
            continue;
        }
    }
    else{break;}
}
args[i]=(char*)0;

_cmd.binary=args[0];
memcpy(_cmd.argv,args,sizeof _cmd.argv);
```

Comment: FWIW, you do realize that `while ((ret=-1))` isn't the same as `while (ret == -1)`, which isn't the right thing to do anyways?

Comment: Bleh, typo! Why wouldn't I want to do that anyway? I'm looping over an environment var (mPath is set using getenv) which is formatted like `/usr/local/sbin#/usr/local/bin#/usr/sbin#/usr/bin#/sbin#/bin#` and looking for c->binary in each of those. If it's not found, execv fails with -1. I guess I could use stat to check if the file is there instead?

Comment: `execvp` handles a `:`-separated `$PATH` just fine.  No, using `stat` first is worse: it's either racy or pointless.

Comment: Per my assignment spec, I'm explicitly told not to use `$PATH` but instead a custom environment variable `$MYPATH` which is `#` delimited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you constructing `c->argv`?  It must be a `NULL`-terminated array of `char *`.  You are likely missing the terminator.

---

In your code handling `<...` and `>...`, you skip over an entry in `argv`, leaving it uninitialized.

Comment: c->argv is defined as `char *argv[6];` (an arbitrary limit set by the homework spec) and is definitely NULL terminated. The shell works fine when I am not using redirection.

Comment: @Airjoe: Can you print out each element in your redirection case to check that this is true?

Comment: I just posted the code for how I am setting up c->argv, but I will do this just to be sure.